# apk installation from downloaded

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'm having trouble getting my app update started. Another program periodically updates the databases from the server, additionally, a new version of the software is imported the same way.

So the issue of importing from the server is already resolved, but I can't create a function that will start the update. It is enough for me to run the file itself and ask for an update.

The file is located in the downloaded location.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of behaviour It's not recommended by Google due to security reasons. (App could be updated without a review by Google Reviewers).

Scenario 1:

If your app, for some reason, needs to be updates before user keeps using it, Google provides a "In-App update" Lib.

Check it out: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates

Scenario 2:

Your app is under development and you want to update your app to the testers.

You have two options:
Firebase app distribution: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution
Testers will be notified when a New version Is release. Firebase will make it easier to them to download the apk/bundle and install it.

Google Play Console test Channel: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=pt-BR

Your app will be on Google Play, but not public. You'll be able to set authorized testers to download it. When you upload a new version to this channel, testers will be notified and will be able to update it, same way It happens with an app that's in production.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I don't think you understood me. As I wrote, my application has already been downloaded from the server and is located in the downloaded directory.

I don't want to publish the app to Google Play, this is a very personalized app for the company.

I want to simply execute the installation from the downloaded directory, as it looks like when clicking on the icon. Użutkownik has to agree, I don't want to do it underneath.